# What is a numerically stable way to remove linearly dependent rows/columns from a large matrix?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

I wish to remove linearly dependent rows/columns of fairly large, real, non-square matrices (around 500x500). Row echelon reduction of course can do this for me with Gaussian elimination, but is there a more numerically stable method available?

Comment: It is already problematic to even detect linear dependent rows NUMERICALLY.

Comment: I think a QR method

Comment: I have expand my reply with a some words on what columns you can eliminate and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context a useful tool is the rank-revealing QR factorization of the matrix $A$. It will allow you to determine how far $A$ is from a matrix of rank $r$.

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be any real matrix with no restrictions on the shape of $A$ (tall/square/wide). Then there exists an orthogonal matrix $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$, a permutations matrix $\Pi$ and an upper triangular matrix $R \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ such that
$$A\Pi = QR.$$ Moreover, the diagonal entries of $R$ are nonnegative and nonincreasing. Let us partition $Q$ and $R$ conformally, and write
$$ A \Pi = \begin{bmatrix} Q_1 & Q_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} R_{11} & R_{12} \\ 0 & R_{22} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} Q_1 R_{11} & Q_1 R_{12} + Q_2 R_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$
Now if say $\|R_{22}\|_F$ is insignificant compared with the smallest singular value of $R_{11}$, then $A\Pi$ is exceedingly close to a matrix whose rank equals the dimension $r$ of $R_{11}$. In fact, the distance to a matrix of rank $r$ is at most $$\|R_{22}\|_2 \leq \|R_{22}\|_F.$$ In this case, you may wish to retain the columns of $A\Pi$ that are given by $Q_1R_{11}$ and discard the rest.

The use of orthogonal transformations in any kind of serious numerical work is preferred over any other kind of transformations simply because they preserve the 2-norm and the Frobenius norm.

Here is a MATLAB implementation of a rank revealing QR factorization based on Givens rotations. I include the dependency and a minimal working example.

```
function [Q, R, pi]=ccGivensQRCP(A)
% ccGivensQR  Computes QR factorization with column pivoting
% 
% CALL SEQUENCE: [Q, R, pi]=ccGivensQRCP(A)
%
% INPUT:
%    A      a real matrix m by n matrix
%
% OUTPUT:
%    Q, R   real matrices such that A(:,pi) = QR where
%             Q  is an m by m orthogonal matrix,
%             R  is an m by n upper triangular matrix
%             pi is a permutation of length m
%
% Moreover, the diagonal elemeents of R are nonincreasing
% 
% MINIMAL WORKING EXAMPLE: ccGivensQRCP_mwe1

% PROGRAMMING by Carl Christian Kjelgaard Mikkelsen (spock@cs.umu.se)
%   2022-10-04  Code adapted from ccGivensQR

% Extract the dimension of the matrix
[m, n]=size(A);

% Initialize the output
Q=eye(m,m); R=A; pi=1:n;

% Allocate space for the column norms of A
colnorm=zeros(1,n);
% Compute the norm of the n columns of A
for j=1:n
    colnorm(j)=norm(R(:,j),2);
end

% Loop over the columns of R
for j=1:n
    % Find the column that has the largest norm
    idx=j;
    for i=j+1:n
        if colnorm(i)>colnorm(idx)
            idx=i;
        end
    end
    % At this point we know that colnorm(i)=max(colnorm)
    
    if idx>j 
        % Swap columns j and idx     
        R(:,[j idx])=R(:,[idx j]);
        % Swap the column norms
        colnorm([j idx])=colnorm([idx j]); 
        % Register the swap as well
        pi([j idx])=pi([idx j]);
    end
    % At this point, we know that the dominant column is leading    
        
    % Process the subdiagonal entries of R(:,j) from the bottom up
    % from the bottom up
    for i=m-1:-1:j
        % Givens rotation needed to nullify R(i+1,j) using R(i,j)
        [c, s, r]=ccGivens(R(i,j),R(i+1,j));
        % Define the matrix that represents Givens rotation 
        G=[c -s; s c]; 
        % Apply the rotation to rows i:i+1 ignoring leading zeros
        R(i:i+1,j+1:end)=G'*R(i:i+1,j+1:end);
        % Explicitly set the entries of R(i:i+1,j)
        R(i:i+1,j)=[r; 0];
        % Accumulate the transformation into Q
        Q(:,i:i+1)=Q(:,i:i+1)*G;
    end
    
    % Compute the norms of the columns of the matrix R(j+1:end,j+1:end)
    % Certainly, this can be done faster, but the slow procedure does 
    % not invite subtractive cancellation.
    for k=j+1:n
        colnorm(k)=norm(R(j+1:end,k),2);
    end
end
```

The dependency:

```
function [c, s, r]=ccGivens(x,y)

% ccGivens  Computes a Givens rotation
%
% CALL SEQUENCE: [c, s, r]=ccGivens(x,y)
%
% INPUT:
%   x    real number
%   y    real number
%
% OUTPUT:
%   c,s  the cosine and sine such that
%          [c -s; s c]'*[x; y] = [r; 0]
%   r    the norm of the vector [x; y]
%
% MINIMAL WORKING EXAMPLE: ccGivens_mwe1

% PROGRAMMING by Carl Christian Kjelgaard Mikkelsen (spock@cs.umu.se)
%   2020-08-20  Initial programming and testing

% Compute the norm of the vector [x,y]
r=norm([x y]);

% Is this a special case?
if abs(x)~=0
    % No, apply the standard formula
    c=x/r; s=y/r;
else
    % Yes, rotate 90 degrees
    c=0; s=1;
end
```

A minimal working example:

```
% Compute a QR factorization with column pivoting.

% Set the dimension of the tall matrix
m=7; n=6; 

% Select the rank r<=n;
r=3; k=n-r;

% Set the random seed
rng(2022);

% //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
% Generate a random matrix of rank r
% //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

% Almost certainly A will have r linearly independent columns 
A=rand(m,r); 
% Generate a random matrix and extend A to n columns
B=rand(k,k); A=[A A*B]; 
% The extra columns are linear combinations of the previous columns
% so we are not increasing the rank

% Shuffle the columns of A randomly
p=randperm(n); A=A(:,p);

% At this point A is almost certainly an m by n matrix of rank r.

% Compute the QR factorization
[Q, R, pi]=ccGivensQRCP(A);

% /////////////////////////////////////
% Verify the factorization
% /////////////////////////////////////

% Compute the residual S
S=A(:,pi)-Q*R; 

% Compute the relative residual
rres=norm(S)/norm(A);

% Check orthogonality
orth=norm(eye(m,m)-Q'*Q,2);

% Display results
fprintf('Relative residual = %8.4e\n',rres);
fprintf('Orthogonality     = %8.4e\n',orth);

% Change the format so that tiny nonzeros are emphasized
format short e

% Display the structure of R
display(R);
% Notice that the diagonal entries decay
% Notice that R has a bunch of tiny entries
% Notice that it is clear that R is close to a matrix of rank r.
```

Answer (score 0):

A numerically stable way to remove linearly dependent rows/columns from a large matrix is to use a QR factorization.

Comment: Is there a reason QR factorisation is more stable/faster/better than reduced row echelon form?

Comment: There is no definitive answer to this question. QR factorization is often used because it is computationally simpler and faster than other methods, such as reduced row echelon form. However, reduced row echelon form may be more stable in some cases. @Hector